# Show function is bounded by using extreme value theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and that
$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$.

How can I prove that $f(x)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ by making use of the extreme value theorem?

Comment: Consider a compact set $K$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$, on $\mathbb{R} - K$. Why can you do that? Now apply the theorem to the function on the domain $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Use the limits to show that there are real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a<b$, $|f(x)|<1$ when $x<a$, and $|f(x)|<1$ when $x>b$. Then consider what you know about $f$ on $[a,b]$.